# Setting up Python for web development on Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the easiest way to set Python 2.7 (and Django) up for web development under Windows 7 (64-bit) with Apache and MySQL?

I know I have to install Apache, MySQL, Python 2.7, Django and mod_wsgi, but I don't understand dependencies, order of actions etc. Is there anyone who understands all this server/database/interface/modules thing, and has an hour to spare to explain it? An answer containing non-specific explanation with a short specific-for-my-case would be preferred, but I would embrace any. Thank you.

**EDIT:** I'll try to be clearer - I want to start developing a web site using Python 2.7 (with Django), I'm using Win 7, and when finished the web site will be hosted on Apache with MySQL. I could not find any tutorial for my specific case (where everything is 64-bit), or one that explains it in general so I can figure out for my self how to make it work. Can anyone give me a short explanation of Python-Django-Apache-MySQL-mod_wsgi relations, or a short list of steps to make it work in my case?

Comment: Rant deleted as off-topic.

Comment: And now my crippled question got all the answers that have nothing to do with it... [Is SO supposed to be a knowledge database?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183732/is-so-supposed-to-be-a-knowledge-database)

Comment: I fail to see how the answers are irrelevant to your question; and SO is many things, but its not a place to come and rant.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid My question was about using Python "with Apache and MySQL".

Comment: See my updated answer @Zemljoradnik. Are you setting up a production environment? If not, then no need to worry about apache or mod_wsgi (as many have stated). 64bit is irrelevant.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I am trying to setup up a production environment. Is 64bit Python going to be working with 32bit mod_wsgi, or Apache?

Comment: No. Stick with 32bit for everything; and I would strongly recommend postgresql over mysql as some of the ORM's features only work in postgresql.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is the easiest way to set Python 2.7 (and Django) up for web
>   development under Windows 7 (64-bit) with Apache and MySQL?

The first thing you need to understand is for development on django you don't need Apache (or even MySQL) installed.

Here is a step-by-step guide (you need to have Administrator privileges on your computer):

1. Download and install Python. Go to [this link](http://python.org/download/) and download the binary installer for Python 2.7.5. It is a msi installer. Save the file to your desktop. Once its finished, double click to install it.
2. Set up the environment. Right click on Computer, then Properties (from the start orb). On the left, click on Advanced System Settings. Click on the Advanced tab, then click on Environment Variables. Click the first New.. (under User Variables). In Variable name, type `PATH`, and in Variable Value, type `C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;%PATH%`. Click OK, and then OK, and then OK.
3. Install `setuptools`. Go to [this link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#downloads) and download the Windows installer for version 2.7. Save this file to your desktop. Once its finished downloading, double click to install it.
4. Installing django. Open up a command prompt. Hit the <kbd>WINDOWS KEY</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type `cmd` and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Then, type `easy_install django`.

Wait till everything is installed.

Now you have all the requirements to begin the django tutorial.

To avoid re-writing stuff, here are links to the various other pieces of software you'll need to get MySQL and Apache installed on Windows for django development.  There is nothing special or different if you are running Windows 64bit or 32bit. It is important however that you download the drivers for the correct version of Python. As of this post date, the current recommended version of Python for django is Python 2, and the latest stable version of *that* is 2.7.5. You'll notice in the downloads for Python that they are postfixed with the Python version number supported. This is important because not all libraries are ported to Python 3.

It is not important in which order the steps are executed; except for the last one which depends on Apache and `mod_wsgi`.

1. To use MySQL with Python on Windows, download the [MySQL drivers for Python](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python) for your Python version. This is a Windows executable, so simply double clicking and going through the wizard is all that is required. These are only the *client libraries*, to install a MySQL *server* download the [MySQL installer](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/) for Windows.
2. For Apache, do not use the "WAMP" installers, instead first [download and install Apache](http://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx), then download the [`mod_wsgi` installer](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DownloadTheSoftware?tm=2) and [configure it for Windows](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationOnWindows).
3. Finally, follow [these steps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/) from the django manual.

As you'll note, the instructions are for **deployment** and not development. For development; you only need to install MySQL and the Python drivers for it.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation (especially the tutorial) for Django, especially the tutorial,  is really quite helpful. Among other things, it points out that there is absolutely no need to install any of Apache, mod_wsgi or MySQL to get started - in fact there is no reason at all to install Apache/mod_wsgi on your development machine, although you may want to install MySQL. But the development environment *only* requires Python (which includes sqlite3) and Django itself.

The [Django installation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/install/) docs explain both of these things, and provide links for Windows downloads of both Python and Django. There really isn't anything that we could explain here in an answer that isn't better explained on that page.

Answer (score -1):

First, take a look to [get Python](http://www.python.org/getit/windows/). Also, see [using Python](http://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html). A simple way to install Django is to use [Django install](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/WindowsInstall).